# spring kafka, get topic size even when empty

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to unlock a `CountDownLatch` when we have successfully read all entries from a topic. My current approach is something like this with Spring Kafka:

```java
private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

@KafkaListener(
  topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(topic = KAFKA_TOPIC, partitions = {"0"}),
  containerFactory = "factory")
public void consume(
    List<Payload> payload,
    Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset) {
        // handle all entries:
        // payload.forEach(eventHandler::handle);

        // offset of last committed message + 1
        int endOffset = consumer.endOffsets(List.of(TOPIC_PART)).get(TOPIC_PART);

        // when we have processed the last entry, we unlock the latch.
        if (offset + payload.size() >= endOffset) {
            latch.countDown();
        }
}
```

The problem is that `latch` will never get unlocked when the Kafka topic is empty, because the method will never run. How can I unlock the latch when the topic is empty?

Comment: What are the values of `offset`, `endOffset` and `payload.size()` in such situation?

Comment: since the topic is empty, the consume() method never ran.

Comment: You should use GetOffsetShell / AdminClient to list topic offsets instead of initializing a consumer. Besides, does the size of your topics never change? Kafka topics don't have any "end" and it's constantly increasing as retention starts removing records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.10/reference/html/#idle-containers and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.10/reference/html/#event-consumption

> The following Spring application events are published by listener containers and their consumers:

> ...

> `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`: published when no messages have been received in `idleInterval` (if configured).

> ...

> The ListenerContainerIdleEvent has the following properties:

> source: The listener container instance that published the event.

> container: The listener container or the parent listener container, if the source container is a child.

> id: The listener ID (or container bean name).

> idleTime: The time the container had been idle when the event was published.

> topicPartitions: The topics and partitions that the container was assigned at the time the event was generated.

> consumer: A reference to the Kafka Consumer object. For example, if the consumer’s pause() method was previously called, it can resume() when the event is received.

> paused: Whether the container is currently paused. See Pausing and Resuming Listener Containers for more information.

```java
public class Listener {

    @KafkaListener(id = "qux", topics = "annotated")
    public void listen4(@Payload String foo, Acknowledgment ack) {
        ...
    }

    @EventListener(condition = "event.listenerId.startsWith('qux-')")
    public void eventHandler(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        ...
    }

}
```